# asp.net mvc load query from controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read my query from controller and I already have the Ajax call to get it through my button. but my problem is there is no changes happening on my index view, the table hasn't change and can't figure out why.

Here is my View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoadInfo";
}

@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.LoadInfo>
<html>
<body>
    <input style="text-align:left; width:250px" id="txtSearch" type="text" />
    <button type="button" id="search" onclick="search()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

    <div class="tableFixHead" ; style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>                    
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.ID</td>
                            <td>@item.Name</td>
                            <td>@item.Address</td>                        
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
function search() {
    var search = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value    

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/LoadInfo',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'name': search                
        },

        success: function (data) {
            alert("success")                

        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadInfo(string name)
{            
    List<readDetails> userDetails = new List<readDetails>();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {                
        string query = "SELECT ID, Name, Address FROM EmpDetails WHERE Name like '%" + name + "%' LIMIT 500";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {                   
                        userDetails.Add(new readDetails
                        {
                            op = sdr["ID"].ToString(),
                            op_desc = sdr["Name"].ToString(),
                            doc_id = sdr["Address"].ToString(),                            
                        });

                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return View(userDetails);    
}
```

I also using this controller to my starting page load not sure if this is cause of the problem, do I need to create a separate controller and view for initial loading and for my search functionality.

The result alerts me to "success" but its weird because my table is not changing or refreshing just like if you do a simple query with filter from query browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function for table's `<tbody>` element to override existing results with the new one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/LoadInfo',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        'name': search                
    },

    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        $('.table tbody').html(data); // override previous results               
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

If the response contains entire `<table>` element, you should omit `tbody` selector:

```
$('.table').html(data);
```

Also you might try to return `PartialView()`, e.g. `return PartialView(userDetails);` instead of entire view page if the search results are provided in same search page.

**Update:**

Since the `data` returns entire HTML page, the current controller action should be modified to return JSON response like this example:

```
public ActionResult LoadInfo(string name)
{            
    List<readDetails> userDetails = new List<readDetails>();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {                
        string query = "SELECT ID, Name, Address FROM EmpDetails WHERE Name like '%" + name + "%' LIMIT 500";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {                   
                        userDetails.Add(new readDetails
                        {
                            op = sdr["ID"].ToString(),
                            op_desc = sdr["Name"].ToString(),
                            doc_id = sdr["Address"].ToString(),                            
                        });

                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return Json(userDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

Then, replace existing `<tbody>` contents with data from response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/LoadInfo',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        'name': search                
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        var tblbody = $('.table').find('tbody');
        tblbody.empty(); // remove existing rows
        var row = '';
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            row += $('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(item.ID), $('<td>').text(item.Name), $('<td>').text(item.Address));
            tblbody.append(row); // add new rows
        });              
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

At this point the search results should appear on the same table instead of returning entire HTML content.

Comment: the results are correct, but it seems like its creating a new table inside the table instead of overriding only the tbody. @Tetsuya

Comment: Is the returned response contains `<table>` element? If my guess is right, then just do `$('.table').html(data)`.

Comment: still the same result no luck.

Comment: I want to see what kind of response returned from controller code, because probably you're returning something different than just `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Comment: yeah I am returning the whole html again and not just the table. how can I return just the table?

Comment: so do I need to create another controller coz like I said I am using it as well from my initial page load. or it directly loads it from my index view.

Comment: You can still use the same controller, but this time returns list content as response which creating table elements by putting `<tr>` and `<td>` tags around the properties (see the updated version).

Comment: i got this result: [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object] from my table body, what is the meaning of this, did it not parsed correctly?

Comment: Probably you're not iterating the correct data here. Try projecting `data` response from AJAX into console and see what kind of data it has.

Comment: I figure out! I just have a missing ending tag from the html, well done! thanks